# LXC PID namespace

Tags: 12.04, lxc

I've been playing around a tad with LXC recently and one of the things I couldn't figure out is how are LXCs in Ubuntu implementing namespacing - in particular PID namespacing.

I can't seem to find any reference to PID namespacing in /proc. Ie:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ ps -ef|grep lxc-start
root     19096     1  0 Oct27 ?        00:00:00 lxc-start -n mysecond -d
vagrant  21431  1037  0 00:28 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto lxc-start
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo ls -l /proc/19096/ns/
total 0
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Oct 27 22:09 ipc
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Oct 27 22:09 net
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Oct 27 22:09 uts
vagrant@precise64:~$
```

Now I can see that ipc, net and uts namespace are indeed in place but no sign of PID one.
I'm sure there is something I'm missing as PID namespacing does seem to work - when I attach to the container's console and run `ps -ef` it does indeed return ONLY a list of processes running inside the LXC - not all processes running on the host.

Anyone idea what should I be looking for ?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you need a sufficiently recent kernel, that is 3.8 or higher, according to author's [blog](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/21/lxc-1-0-your-second-container/).